# Material-Table columns not resizable with more than 5 columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I am displaying data using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/).  I have 19 columns to display and I want to set a fixed size for each column.  Using `width: 45%` is not making any visual changes.  I can't use `whiteSpace: "nowrap"` because that will only make the table longer and more difficult to use when some cells have large sentences.  I have tried using `width`, `cellStyle` and `headerStyle` in all 19 of my columns but it made no difference.

Here are some of my columns and my table:

```
const columns = [
        { title: "Sizing ID", field: "SizingId" },
        { title: "Intake ID", field: "IntakeID" },
        { title: "FCRID", field: "FCRID" },
        { title: "Taxonomy ID", field: "TaxonomyId" },
        { title: "Domain", field: "Domain" },
        { title: "Experience", field: "Experience" },
        { title: "Product Line", field: "ProductLine" },
        { title: "Sizing Contact", field: "SizingContact" },
        { title: "Q1Cost", field: "Q1Cost" },
        { title: "Sizing Comments", field: "SizingComments" },
];
...

<MaterialTable
    title="Sizing"
    data={sizing.sizing}
    columns={columns}
    options={{
        pageSize: 15,
        pageSizeOptions: [15, 25, 50],
        padding: "dense",
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#0076CE",
            color: "#e5e6e7",
            fontFamily: "sans-serif",
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: 600,
            maxWidth: 200,
        },
        rowStyle: (data, index) => {
            if (index % 2) {
                return {
                    backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE",
                    fontSize: 12,
                };
            } else {
                return { fontSize: 12 };
            }
        },
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use Fixed columns with a large number of columns in the docs
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/fixed-columns

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).